# golang convert big.Float to big.Int

Tags: go

convert big.Float to big.Int, i write code below, but it overflow with uint64, so what's the correct way to cenvert big.Float to big.Int.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "math/big"

func FloatToBigInt(val float64) *big.Int {
    bigval := new(big.Float)
    bigval.SetFloat64(val)

    coin := new(big.Float)
    coin.SetInt(big.NewInt(1000000000000000000))
    bigval.Mul(bigval, coin)

    result := new(big.Int)
    f,_ := bigval.Uint64()
    result.SetUint64(f)

    return result
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("vim-go")
    fmt.Println(FloatToBigInt(float64(10)))
    fmt.Println(FloatToBigInt(float64(20)))
    fmt.Println(FloatToBigInt(float64(30)))
    fmt.Println(FloatToBigInt(float64(40)))
    fmt.Println(FloatToBigInt(float64(50)))
    fmt.Println(FloatToBigInt(float64(100)))
    fmt.Println(FloatToBigInt(float64(1000)))
    fmt.Println(FloatToBigInt(float64(10000)))
}
```

Answer (score 10):

A big int bigger than `uint64` will always cause an overflow as `uint64` has fixed size. You should use the following [method](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Float.Int) on `*Float`:

```
func (*Float) Int
```

The changes required would be:

```
func FloatToBigInt(val float64) *big.Int {
    bigval := new(big.Float)
    bigval.SetFloat64(val)
    // Set precision if required.
    // bigval.SetPrec(64)

    coin := new(big.Float)
    coin.SetInt(big.NewInt(1000000000000000000))

    bigval.Mul(bigval, coin)

    result := new(big.Int)
    bigval.Int(result) // store converted number in result

    return result
}
```

Working example: https://play.golang.org/p/sEhH6iPkrK

Comment: thanks it works . but you see this example https://play.golang.org/p/P02AN1e09C it also has some problem.

Comment: `bigval` has a default precision of 53 bits. You need to increase this value to get accurate result: https://play.golang.org/p/Xy88JX57JE.
You'll need to read up on float precision documents to determine the number of bits your program requires.

Answer (score 1):

Use the function [Float.Int(nil)](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Float.Int)

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with a regular float64 number (not big.Float) and found out that conversion via string is the most precise way. Check it out

Note: the example is for float64 -> decimal(,20) conversion.

```golang
func bigIntViaString(flt float64) (b *big.Int) {

    if math.IsNaN(flt) || math.IsInf(flt, 0) {
        return nil // illegal case
    }

    var in = strconv.FormatFloat(flt, 'f', -1, 64)

    const parts = 2

    var ss = strings.SplitN(in, ".", parts)

    // protect from numbers without period
    if len(ss) != parts {
        ss = append(ss, "0")
    }

    // protect from ".0" and "0." values
    if ss[0] == "" {
        ss[0] = "0"
    }

    if ss[1] == "" {
        ss[1] = "0"
    }

    const (
        base     = 10
        fraction = 20
    )

    // get fraction length
    var fract = len(ss[1])
    if fract > fraction {
        ss[1], fract = ss[1][:fraction], fraction
    }

    in = strings.Join([]string{ss[0], ss[1]}, "")
    // convert to big integer from the string
    b, _ = big.NewInt(0).SetString(in, base)
    if fract == fraction {
        return // ready
    }
    // fract < 20, * (20 - fract)
    var (
        ten = big.NewInt(base)
        exp = ten.Exp(ten, big.NewInt(fraction-int64(fract)), nil)
    )
    b = b.Mul(b, exp)
    return

}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/_lkyQ_0udjd

Answer (score 0):

My example, exactly to convert big.Float to big.Int

```golang
func floatToInt(input *big.Float) *big.Int {
    out, _ := input.Int(new(big.Int))
    return out
}
```

And, just in case, backward converting

```golang
func intToFloat(input *big.Int) *big.Float {
    return new(big.Float).SetInt(input)
}
```

I hope it's helps anyone.