# Strange loss of precision multiplying big.Float

Tags: go

If you parse a string into a big.Float like `f.SetString("0.001")`, then multiply it, I'm seeing a loss of precision. If I use `f.SetFloat64(0.001)`, I don't lose precision. Even doing a `strconv.ParseFloat("0.001", 64)`, then calling `f.SetFloat()` works.

Full example of what I'm seeing here:

https://play.golang.org/p/_AyTHJJBUeL

Expanded from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47546136/105562

Answer (score 1):

The difference in output is due to imprecise representation of base 10 floating point numbers in `float64` ([IEEE-754 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)) and the default precision and rounding of [`big.Float`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Float).

See this simple code to verify:

```
fmt.Printf("%.30f\n", 0.001)
f, ok := new(big.Float).SetString("0.001")
fmt.Println(f.Prec(), ok)
```

Output of the above (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-lYbQw1U8lE)):

```
0.001000000000000000020816681712
64 true
```

So what we see is that the `float64` value `0.001` is not exactly `0.001`, and the default precision of `big.Float` is 64.

If you increase the precision of the number you set via a `string` value, you will see the same output:

```
s := "0.001"
f := new(big.Float)
f.SetPrec(100)
f.SetString(s)
fmt.Println(s)
fmt.Println(BigFloatToBigInt(f))
```

Now output will also be the same (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/LjWbA8-YKcc)):

```
0.001
1000000000000000
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, and I had actually tried that, but I used `SetPrec(128)` and that doesn't work. Turns out 128 and 64 don't work, work but everything around it does... Any idea why that is? See results here: https://play.golang.org/p/KLnPY8cqKpe

Comment: @TravisReeder I assume it is due to the fact that `0.001` cannot be represented precisely, and when using finite bits, the implementation rounds `0.001` to the closest number representable using the given precision. Sometimes it might mean to round up, sometimes to round down.